# How to change gesture interpolation from x-axis to y-axis in React Navigation screenInterpolator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm running into a problem where I'd like the user to be able to slide their finger down the y-axis and the screen will go down with it, but unfortunately right now if the user slides across the x-axis (from left to right) the screen will interpolate that down the y-axis.

Here's a gif of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5BN5.jpg

```
export const ExchangeNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    addExchange: { screen: AddExchangeScreen },
    addCoinbase: { screen: AddCoinbaseScreen },
    addBinance: { screen: AddBinanceScreen },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      gesturesEnabled: true,
    },
    transitionConfig: TransitionConfiguration,
  },
)

export default ExchangeNavigator


export const SlideToTopTransition = (index, position) => {
  const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 0.99, index + 1]

  const translateY = position.interpolate({
    inputRange,
    outputRange: [DEVICE_RESOLUTION.height, 0, 0, 0],
  })

  return { transform: [{ translateY }] }
}

export const TransitionConfiguration = () => {
  return {
    transitionSpec: {
      useNativeDriver: true
    },
    // Define scene interpolation, eq. custom transition
    screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
      const { position, scene } = sceneProps
      const { index, route } = scene
      const params = route.params || {}
      const transition = params.transition || 'default'

      return {
        slideToTop: SlideToTopTransition(index, position),
        slideToRight: SlideToRightTransition(index, position),
        slideToLeft: SlideToLeftTransition(index, position),
        modalTransition: ModalTransition(index, position),
        fadeTransition: FadeTransition(index, position),
        default: SlideToTopTransition(index, position),
      }[transition]
    },
  }
}

export default TransitionConfiguration
```

What's the best way to change the user gesture from left to right -> top to bottom & interpolate on the y-axis accordingly?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Set the mode of the navigator to mode. See the configuration under 'Note: Invert the pan responder axis' section in this blog post https://blog.coder.si/2018/11/react-native-navigation-custom-scene.html